# Bootstrap Modal layer superimposed on jquery autocomplete result

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In developing a C# ASPNET MVC application I have several page with a jquery autocomplete, working just fine, like this:
[image]

As I am now introducing Bootstrap Modals to show this kind of stuff, i ran into this strange behavior. Again, data retrieval works fine **but results are being displayed behind the Modal layer**, like this:
[image]

Has it to do with wrong CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to append the menu to the modal div element.

Ref:
[jQuery Autocomplete Widget u.i.](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo)